# Existe a expressão "pular sessão" ou somente "pular seção"?

Tags: expressões

É uma dúvida que eu tenho, a expressão "pular seção" é corriqueira quando falamos de documentos, mas, existe a expressão "pular sessão" referente a algum intervalo de tempo?

Comment: Não conheço essa expressão — Não se trataria apenas uma frase? Algo como "A seção 3 não está pronta ainda, então vamos pular essa seção."

Comment: O problema está no sessão e seção, não no salto.